# Changes detection doesn't work properly in Angular2

Tags: angular

In ngOnInit() I have a subscription on a Subject, which sends new data when I get a new response in my service from the EventSource:

```
this._orderService.onNewOrderLoaded$
  .subscribe(order => {
    this.orders.push(order)
    this.orders.sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id)
    this.orders = this.orders.slice()
    this.notify()
  })

this._orderService.openSSEConnection()
```

In my template I have a simple table, that displays orders:

```
<tr *ngFor="let order of orders">
...
</tr>
```

But component doesn't rerender when in subscription in `ngOnInit()` I get new orders and change orders' model using `.slice()`. So I detect changes manualy using `this._ref.detectChanges()`. It is the first question: How can I rerender component without `detectChanges()` when I get a new order in subscription?

And the seconds problem is that when I use `detectChanges()` and rerender table of orders, `(click)` method doesn't update model of new order too. `(click)` of `<td></td>` calls function:

```
viewOrder(order: Order) {
    this.selectedOrder = { ...order }
    this.isInfoModalOpened = true
}
```

This function changes `isInfoModalOpened` and `selectedOrder` so modal component can be displayed:

```
<app-modal-component *ngIf="isInfoModalOpened" [order]="selectedOrder">
```

But it doesn't work too, so or I need to call `detectChanges()` manualy or I need to click on some element, that will cause changes detection.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 change detection - push data into array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60036967/angular-2-change-detection-push-data-into-array)

Comment: Your components are not onPush right..? I have never ever needed to manually do detectChanges..there is really nothing wrong with change detection in Angular 